# Force close on break point

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

Has anybody experienced getting a forced close on their apps because of a breakpoint? When I try to run normally, the app does not close.

It also gives this error on the logcat:

```
09-11 23:46:35.346 32708-32708/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx A/libc: Fatal signal 11
(SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x28 in tid 32708 (jumblednameofapplicationclass)
```

Comment: Any logcat? Are you using picaso?

Comment: The logcat does not indicate the cause of the crash. So I didn't include it.  I'm using picasso, but the area of code that I've used a breakpoint does not use picasso.

Comment: Ok. I was facing the same problem like yours. App was crashing without reason. After that I search for it in logcat and found that app crashing due to picasso. Picasso throwing SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: When you have a crash like that, it usually means that you have a race condition that stopping one thread is causing to become more likely.  In this case, it looks like either an object you pass to some C code is null in this case, and the C code isn't checking.(we can tell by the address, which is very close to 0, so it most likely a derefrenced null with offset).

Comment: @GabeSechan: You are probably right. I will investigate this and if you are correct I'll notify you to post your answer and I will accept it.